# [python] output of a code be called in another python code automatically

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a robot equipped with different sensors. one of them is 3d lidar. i have used the pointcloud and converted them into lasersacn. now i have written a simple python code which do object detction and specify the distance from the nearest object to the lidar based on the lasersan ranges. this is the first code, now i have written another code which should use this value and start moving and stop when it reach near the object. now my problem is that i want the distance value specified in the first code(output of the first code, for instance it would say 10 m to the object), automatically be called in the second code. what should i do?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405140/%5Bpython%5D-output-of-a-code-be-called-in-another-python-code-automatically/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many choices/design decisions to take at this point.

1. The simplest idea is to publish the distance value as a latched topic. Then, in your second program, please make a subscriber, listening to the published topic. This way, you can easily get the distance value in your second program.
2. Another approach could be making use of ROS Service. On the first program (node), please make a service server that returns the distance from the object. Then, please create a service client on the second program (node) to get the distance value.

Once you have the distance value, you can execute the move command.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-17**:
thanks a lot

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-17**:
@Ravi Joshi
i want to use the first suggestion, I have defined publisher in the first code and subscriber in the second code. now just running the first code and then the second code would be ok?